# Functiοnal Εquation in Real Line

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find all functions  $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb R $ such that $f(n)f(n+2)+f(n+1)=1$ for all positive integers $n\geq 1$.

*My Work*

I put $n=1,2$: $~f(1)f(3)+f(2)=1=f(2)f(4)+f(3)~$ so $~f(2)(f(4)-1)-f(3)(f(1)-1)=0$, but I can find anything.

Comment: We cannot find $f(x)$ when $x$ is not an integer. It is impossible.

Comment: Weijun's remark is valid even if you consider smooth functions.
What you have here is a recurrence relation defining sequences. You need to see how many degrees of liberty it has.

Comment: Let f:N->R. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Starting with $n=0$, $f_0=a$, $f_1=b$, we can observe that
the sequence $f_n$,
\begin{align} 
f_{n+2}&=\frac{1-f_{n+1}}{f_n}
,
\end{align}

is periodic with period 5, $f(n+5)=f(n)$:

\begin{align} 
f_2&=\frac{1-b}a
,\\
f_3&=\frac{a+b-1}{ab}
,\\
f_4&=\frac{1-a}{b}
,\\
f_5&=a
,\\
f_6&=b
,\\
\dots
\end{align}

The simplest solution would be 
a constant function
\begin{align} 
f(x)&=a
,\\
a^2+a-1&=0
,\\
a&=-\tfrac12\pm \tfrac{\sqrt{5}}2
.
\end{align}

Comment: What is the value of f(6) if a=1,b=2?

Comment: @primes.wizard: 
In case $a=1,b=2$ we have $f_3=1,f_4=0,f_5=1=a$,
and the periodic solution will still work,
if we consider $f_6=\lim_{a\to1}\frac{(1-a)\,b}{(1-a)}=b$.
But for the original relation $f_nf_{n+2}+f_{n+1}=1$
in this case we have $0\cdot f_6+1=1$,
so any real $f_6$ will fit.
So, yes,
you also need to consider cases when $f_n=0$ separately.
Obviously, not all combinations of $a,b$ will be valid,
for example, $a=0,b\ne1$.

Comment: Thanks about your answer. One last question: when f(i)=0 then can we find exactly the terms of the sequence?

Comment: @primes.wizard: 
No. As soon as $f_n=0$, 
the original relation $f_nf_{n+2}+f_{n+1}=1$
demands that $f_{n+1}=1$,
but we can't be certain about $f_{n+2}$.